# how can i get the search result in the form of list counter in android

Tags: android, search, arraylist, android-recyclerview, counter

I want to display the search result in the form of counter means if i search something in title bar i should get the total number of elements in that list.
Example i have given in the image in which there are 2 recycler views in which one is horizontal which is category and vertical is elements present in list. What i want is when i search something i should get total number of elements present in that category in the form of counter like in the image counter provided.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If noone else answers, I'll give you a general overview:

You define Recyclerview Items, perhaps with Contraintlayouts in this case.
You put a TextView ontop of the Circle in the back and give the TextView a round background shape using the shapes xml file (you might have to create one in your project).

The TextView just needs to have a end and bottom constraint and some margin.

When the search changes, use notifyDatasetChanged() on the Recyclerview and calculate the new numbers.

Comment: That's what I meant, a single recyclerview item has the big circle and then a TextView with a circle background. That's your counter.

Comment: i don't want xml part what i want is when i type in search bar for any category i want to display the total numbers of elements present in that  category in the form of counter

Comment: For that we need some code, what exactly identifies that category? You can just use a forEach loop on the list and count the occurances of each item in a specific category. Then you can set that with the xml part.

Comment: okay i will definitely try that but can you tell me that my counter is in horizontal recycler adapter and want to get the count list form vertical reycler adapter how can i achieve this ?

Comment: The data source needs to be somewhere outside of the Recycerview, in that case you can just pass/get the amount in the other Recyclerview. Meaning if it's a variable in Mainactivity, you can just pass it to the other recyclerview or just pass the amounts.